# Split string into two separated by colon with regex in Java and ignore colons within tags and quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have been trying to figure out a Java RegEx for some while now that would split something like the following into two pieces:
`l&<6:98>9"hello:world"-45:&<78:89>"hedhed:hdeh"+56`
it should be split at the colon after "-45" ignoring all colons inside tags and quotes. Neither of the sides must not necessarily contain any tags or quotes.

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think that's a task for a simple parsing function.

Comment: that might be possible... I will try...

Comment: Can you explain what "Neither of the sides must not necessarily contain any tags or quotes" means? Do you mean "Neither side needs to contain tags or quotes" or "Neither side can contain tags or quotes" or some other thing?

Comment: it is not necessary for any of the two sides to have any occurances of either quotes and/or tags. Both sides may contain, but they must not necessarily do so. Sorry for my little extra "not", noticed it now :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to perform matching rather than splitting.

```
(?:[^"<:]|"[^"]*"|<[^>]*)*
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be a starting point for a parsing function:

```
/** example: findCharIndex(subject, ':'); */
public static int findCharIndex(String subject, char findChar)
{
    boolean insideQuotes = false;
    boolean insideTags = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < subject.length(); index++)
    {
        char ch = subject.charAt(index);
        if (ch == '"')
            insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
        else if (!insideQuotes)
        {
            if (ch == '<')
                insideTags = true;
            else if (insideTags && ch == '>')
                insideTags = false;
        }
        if (!insideQuotes && !insideTags && ch == findChar)
            return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @Anto: Probably my function performs faster, but the regex solution by @KennyTM is smarter.

Comment: I thought something similar, but I think that today computers are still so powerful you wouldn't notice it in the kind of program I am making (line based text editor)